# Mpdboot: Deprecation Warning

Tags: python, mpi, mpich, mpiexec

I am trying to use the mpdboot command to start 4 processors on which to run my MPI program. I created a mpd.hosts file with 4 nodes (75, 77, 79 and 80). Each of them run python 2.3.4. I also modified the bashrc and cshrc files to ensure that the variables contain the path to the directory of the compiler libraries. I also set up the mpd.conf file and checked that it has rw (600) permissions.

I have copied below the output screen when I run mpdboot

[n@heart]$ mpdboot -n 4 -r ssh

:38: Deprecation Warning: The popen2 module is deprecated.  Use the subprocess module.

n@75's password:xxx

n@77's password:xxx

n@79's password:xxx

n@80's password:xxx

mpdboot_heart.int(err_exit 526): mpd failed to start correctly on heart.int

reason: 0: invalid port from mpd /opt/intel/mpi/2.0/bin/mpd.py:85: DeprecationWarning: the md5 module is deprecated; use hashlib instead

Killed

---

PART 2:

I also logged into one of the nodes and tried running mpdboot. Here is the output by doing that

[n@79 ~]$ mpdboot -n 4 -r ssh

n@75's password:xxx

n@77's password:xxx

n@79's password:xxx

n@80's password:xxx

mpdboot_79_0 (mpdboot 499): problem has been detected during mpd(boot) startup at 1 75; output:

Permission denied, please try again.

n@75's password: Permission denied, please try again.

n@77's password: mpdboot_79_0 (mpdboot 515): problem has been detected during mpd(boot) startup at 2 77; output:

Permission denied, please try again.

Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password).

n@77's password: Permission denied, please try again.

Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password).

---

How should I proceed on this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few points:

1. You really [don't want to use MPD](http://wiki.mcs.anl.gov/mpich2/index.php/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Q%3a_I_don.27t_like_.3CWHATEVER.3E_about_mpd.2C_or_I.27m_having_a_problem_with_mpdboot.2C_can_you_fix_it.3F) anymore.  That process manager has been deprecated and replaced with the [hydra process manager](http://wiki.mcs.anl.gov/mpich2/index.php/Using_the_Hydra_Process_Manager).
2. You must be using an old version of MPD (old version of MPICH2) because AFAIK all of those deprecation warnings were fixed as of the 1.1 release.  I doubt you are actually running Python 2.3.4 because I think that those warnings were added to Python in version 2.6.
3. With respect to "PART 2", you have a bad ssh configuration.  You need to make sure that passwordless ssh (with ssh keys) works correctly between all hosts.  This will be necessary even if you switch to the hydra process manager, although you may receive a nicer error message in that case.

Comment: Thanks Dave. When I do, ssh <nodename> python -V, it does give me 2.3.4. Also, as far as the above issue is concerned, could it be an issue with how I link my iccvars.sh, bashrc or cshrc files? I could post the contents of those and the path if that could be useful to shed some light.

Comment: Try updating to the [current version](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpich2/downloads/index.php?s=downloads) of MPICH2 (1.4) and using hydra.  That will avoid python and MPD issues entirely (no more mpdboot step).  You will still need to solve your passwordless ssh issue though.

Comment: Great! Thank you! So, once I have this...what is the next step? I do have an MPI application to run. I have tested it on a single node with 4 processors. I use the mpirun command to submit my job. This whole effort was me trying to use more nodes...Hence, once MPICH (1.4) is installed, what are things I need to take care off before I submit a job?

Comment: I did find the documentation on your website and plan to work through it. Are there any system requirements to be able to install MPICH(1.4)? We are presently running Centos 5.5 w/ python 2.4.3 and this has OpenMPI 1.4.3 installed.

Comment: Your system sounds fine for installing MPICH2. If you don't have a fortran compiler then you may need to pass "--disable-f77 --disable-fc" to configure. Better yet, try installing a binary package if one is available for Centos 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

Is mpdboot compatible with such a version of python? That's downright ancient, I didn't know there was even any distribution left that still shipped 2.3. Have you tried with 2.7?

Comment: How does one check compatibility?  I am working with the "Intel MPI Library for Linux* OS getting started guide" and it says that I have to verify the installed Python version is 2.2 or higher. The ones I currently have installed are 2.3.4

Comment: @Ashmohan: That seems to suggest that it is supported. At this point you should look at your code and check for bugs there. Deprecation warnings are (mostly) harmless -- they just mean that a function you're calling may be removed in future versions.